# Удалить часть строки в bash(regexp?)?

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, bash, gnu

На входе имеем string: "/path/t/o/filename.mp3" или "/path/t/o/filename.wav" и тд(различные расширения). На выходе нужно получить только filename. Как это сделать средствами bash и GNU утилит(и возможно ли)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/125281/4827341

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На входе можно даже иметь список путей и обрабатывать их потоковым текстовым редактором [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). Пример использования для вашего случая:

```
echo "/path/t/o/filename.wav" | sed -re 's#^.*/([^/.]+)\.[^.]+$#\1#'
```

В этой команде `s#^.*/([^/.]+)\.[^.]+$#\1#` означает:

`s` - делать поиск и замену

`^.*/([^/.]+)\.[^.]+$` регулярка что ищем и захватываем

`\1` заменяем, то что нашли на захваченный шаблон

`#` символ разделитель

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "/path/t/o/filename.wav" | awk -F'[/.]' '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

`-F'[/.]'` - установить разделителем **полей** -- слэш(/) и точку(.)

`$(NF-1)` - вывести предпоследнее **поле**

Comment: предложенное решение не будет работать например для файла archive.tar.gz

Comment: @aleksey-vaganov , 
а разве стояла такая задача ? я исходил из тех примеров которы предоставил автор вопроса, а именно `"/path/t/o/filename.mp3" или "/path/t/o/filename.wav"`, где есть путь и где есть файл с одним расширением. Зачем придумывать лишние условия, при желании можно даже предположить такой вариант - `/path/t/o/file.name.mp3` где в самом имени могут быть точки, но зачем ?

Comment: стояла задача получить имя файла

Comment: @aleksey-vaganov, 
нет, если бы стояла задача получить имя файла то для этого хватило бы и простой команды `basename`. Не нужно путать Windows подход к построению имён файлов, в Linux нет такого понятия, как расширение имени файла.